# Conditionals from within Piped String of values

Tags: categories, conditionals, low-seg2cat

I have a string of piped category ID's which represent all the categories which are selected for any given page.

Within my page, I now need to check the input of the chosen categories.

For example, I have `{segment_category_ids_piped}` (I'm using Low Seg2Cat) - this returns `"3|5|6|14"`.

In my category loop, I now need to check the checkbox if the category exists. The code I have at the moment is :

`<li><input type="checkbox" {if segment_category_ids_piped *= cat_id}checked="checked"{/if}><a href="#" title="{cat_name}">{cat_name}<span>({entry_count})</span></a></li>`

The problem is that it's treated as a literal string, so if I loop through my categories, it's showing cat_id 1 and 4 as being selected, because they are represented in the string for 14.

I'm presuming that a regular expression would be needed here, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to the syntax (RegExp has never been a strong point of mine!).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
{if segment_category_ids_piped ~ '/\b'.cat_id.'\b/'}
```

Note: this works for pipe-separated **IDs** (numbers). If you're looking for pipe-separated strings or text, you'd be better off using this:

```
{if piped_text ~ '/(^|\|)'.text.'(\||$)/'}
```