# Issue using category_id in IF statement when entry has multiple categories

Tags: categories

this code has worked great for a long time.  I pull entries and use an IF statement around which category they are in:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="on" limit="1"}

    {if "{categories}{category_id}{/categories}” == “44” OR “{categories}{category_id}{/categories}” == “191” } 
    ....
    {/if}

    {if "{categories}{category_id}{/categories}” == “45”}
      ....
    {/if}
```

All was good until I got an entry with more than one category (84 & 191).  The output is `{category_id} = “84191”` which doesn't get caught in my conditional.

I don’t want to use the “contains” conditional b/c then an entry with category 84 & 4 would be “844” and would match me looking for category=44.  How do I solve this??

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionals from within Piped String of values](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30318/conditionals-from-within-piped-string-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent your issue with 84 & 4 occurring, you could use code like this, where you surround the category IDs with something to make them separate:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="on" limit="1"}

    {if "{categories}({category_id}){/categories}" *= "(44)" OR "{categories}({category_id}){/categories}" == "191" } 
    ....
    {/if}

    {if "{categories}({category_id}){/categories}" *= "(45)"}
    ....
    {/if}
```

Depending on your use case, it might be better written as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="on" limit="1"}
    {categories}
        {if "{category_id}" == "44" OR "{category_id}" == "191" }
        ....
        {/if}

        {if "{category_id}" == "45"}
        ....
        {/if}
    {/categories}
```

Though then you'd get output twice if your entry was in both categories 44 and 191.

Comment: adding the parenthesis works great!  thanks